# Another version of Hahn-Banach for restriction of a functional?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to understand some sentences in a course in functional analysis conway:

[image]

What is the meaning of annotated text? (my confusion is : Hahn-Banach is for existence of extension of a function not existence of restriction. )

Comment: That sentence just translates to "for every bounded linear functional $f$ on $M$, there is a (this is what's meant by 'obtainable') bounded linear functional $F$ on $X$ such that $F|_M=f$". It means the same as $f$ having an extension. This is of course what Hahn-Banach says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hahn-Banach theorem states that every bounded functional in $\mathcal{M}^*$ can be extended to a bounded functional in $\mathcal{X}^*$. Thus there are no bounded functionals in $\mathcal{M}^*$ that aren't the restriction of a bounded functional in $\mathcal{X}^*$. Thus, as the annotated text states, "every bounded linear functional on  $\mathcal{M}$ is obtainable as a restriction of a functional from $\mathcal{X}^*$".